# How to store array as variables in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm new to python and stuck with a folder of files that I can't structure.
I have several files (.gra) that I'm importing as numpy arrays using python. These arrays are meteorological variables (GFS) both in 3D and 2D.

The 3D variables are for different altitudes in a polygon (a location). I know that each variable is storage together until the next one start. 3D variables are located first and 2D after.

I would like to create a function that iterates a folder, read each file and, given a step, storage each slice of the array assigned to a key.

My final purpose is to have a dictionary with all data of each variable stored by date.

The output I want is a dataframe of 3 columns (id(date), all meteorological data selected for each date by variable name).

I have tried to create a dictionary with all variables and set up a json file to help me determine the range of elements that contain each variable in the array.

```
gfs_info = {
    "HGTprs": (0,3_042), "CLWMRprs": (3_042, 6_084),"RHprs": (6_084,9_126),
    "Velprs": (9_126,12_168),"UGRDprs": (12_168,15_210),"VGRDprs": (15_210,18_252),
    "TMPprs": (18_252,21_294),"HGTsfc": (21_294,21_411),"MSLETmsl": (21_411,21_528),
    "PWATclm": (21_528,21_645),"RH2m": (21_645,21_762),"Vel100m": (21_762,21_879),
    "UGRD100m": (21_879,21_996),"VGRD100m": (21_996,22_113),"Vel80m": (22_113,22_230),
    "UGRD80m": (22_230,22_347),"VGRD80m": (22_347,22_464),"Vel10m":(22_464,22_581),
    "UGRD10m": (22_581,22_698),"VGRD10m": (22_698,22_815),"GUSTsfc": (22_815,22_932),
    "TMPsfc": (22_932,23_049),"TMP2m": (23_049,23_166),"no4LFTXsfc":(23_166,23_283),
    "CAPEsfc": (23_283,23_400),"SPFH2m": (23_400,23_517),"SPFH80m": (23_517,23_634),
}
```

From the 7th key, onwards, the jump is made from 117 to 117 instead of 3042

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: what do the values like `3_042` represent ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Could you give a clear expected output ?